# Configurable package in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, configurable-product, extensions, package

Is it possible to create product page like this

http://tpy-urbancolors.com.tempwebsite.net/products/c13-montana-black-400ml/

Please guide me or suggest any extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No extension is required** to add more products in a single click.

Just create a Group Product & add associated products inside this & see the output in frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you please send me any reference link or tutorial about that.

Comment: Please see here- http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-add-and-manage-grouped-products.html

Answer (score 0):

The most recommended module would be:

[Color Swatches Pro by Amasty](https://amasty.com/color-swatches-pro.html)

Comment: No but i need to add more products in a single click, See my reference link